# Join a table on itself

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have a table `ValuationHistory` with the following columns

```
Code | ValuationDate | NetAssetValue | PricePerShare | Subscriptions | Redemptions  
ABC  | 2014-06-30    | 12546.50      | 100.23        | 60            | 70  
CEF  | 2014-06-30    | 10025.20      | 120.50        | 30            | 20  
ABC  | 2014-07-31    | 12505.50      | 101.50        | 40            | 60  
ABC  | 2014-08-31    | 13051.41      | 102.50        | 35            | 70
```

Now the user will select a Valuation date and a code from an aspx page. I want to write an sql query that will give me a report with the following columns for all the valuation dates prior to the valuation date selected by the user

```
Code | BeginningEquity | Subscriptions | Redemptions | EndingEquity
```

Where

- `Code` is the code selected by the user
- `BeginningEquity` is the `NetAssetValue` for the previous valuation
- `Subscriptions` is straight forward
- `Redemptions` is straight forward
- `EndingEquity` is the `NetAssetValue` on the `valuationDate`

I first created a table variable called `@ValDates` and got all the valuation dates into this temp table. Then I did a join of `@ValDates` with the `ValuationHistory` table.

But I am getting an error on the following query. The error message is:

> subquery returned more than one value

Could somebody help me write this query in a better way

```
SELECT (SELECT NetAssetValue 
        FROM   ValuationHistory 
        WHERE  ValuationDate IN (SELECT Max(ValuationDate) 
                                 FROM   ValuationHistory 
                                 WHERE  ValuationDate < nd.ValuationDate)), 
       Subscriptions, 
       Redemptions, 
       EndingEquity 
FROM   ValuationHistory vh 
       INNER JOIN @ValDates vd 
               ON vh.ValuationDate = vd.ValuationDate 
WHERE  vh.Code = @Code 
       AND vh.ValuationDate < = @ValuationDate
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 NetAssetValue `?

Comment: Thank you Tim, first of all for formatting my question properly. "Top 1" fixed my subquery returned more than one value error but now it seems that BeginningEquity and EndingEquity have the same values

Comment: what's your desire output for the sample data list?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear about your requirement. Based on the description, you may try to start your query as below

```
DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(10) = 'ABC'
       ,@ValuationDate date = '2014-07-31'

;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY ValuationDate), *
  FROM ValuationHistory
 )
SELECT 
  c1.Code,
  c2.NetAssetValue AS BeginningEquity,
  c2.ValuationDate AS BeginningDate,
  c1.NetAssetValue AS EndingEquity,
  c1.ValuationDate AS EndingDate,
  c1.[Subscriptions], 
  c1.[Redemptions]
from cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2 
  ON c1.Code = c2.Code
  AND c2.rn = c1.rn - 1
WHERE  c1.Code = @Code 
AND c1.ValuationDate < = @ValuationDate
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97597/1)

Comment: Thanks Eric... Let me try this